# How to alphabetically sort array of dictionaries on single key?

Tags: python, facebook, list, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort the list of friends returned by Facebook's Graph API.  The result after sorting needs to be an alphabetical order of friends by name.

```
[
      {
         "name": "Joe Smith",
         "id": "6500000"
      },
      {
         "name": "Andrew Smith",
         "id": "82000"
      },
      {
         "name": "Dora Smith",
         "id": "97000000"
      },
      {
         "name": "Jacki Smith",
         "id": "107000"
      }
]
```

Additional notes:  I am running on Google App Engine, which uses Python 2.5.x.

Comment: Google App Engine uses Python 2.5: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your list is called `A`, you can sort it this way using:

`A.sort(cmp = lambda x,y: cmp(x["name"],y["name"]))`

Comment: -1. This is expensive and deprecated. MHC's approach using the key is superior.

Comment: This is very time consuming for friends lists of 100+, but it works and the other don't.  Hmmmm.

Answer (score 8):

```
sorted(flist, key=lambda friend: friend["name"])
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  I should note I'm on Python 1.5.x, due to running on Google App Engine.

Comment: Both `sorted()` function and `key` argument in list.sort() requires version 2.4 and newer. I don't know whether @charleyc 's method would work for the 1.5.x version.

Comment: I guess you will have to use it or manually implement more efficient sorting algorithm. I haven't looked at Google App Engine, but it forces you using 1.5.x Python? Well...

Comment: Google App Engine is not built on 1.5.x.  You are using 2.5: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html

Comment: My typo, meant 2.5.  I'm a Java programmer new to Python.  But this begs the question, why isn't sorted() working?

Comment: Sorted does not sort in place, so you have to assign the value returned by it to a new list variable (or back to the same list variable). Conversely, list.sort(key=...) sorts the list in place. Ned Batchelder is pretty top notch as Python advice goes, so if what he suggests isn't working for you, then I'd say you should reread his advice and/or the docs.

Answer (score 4):

```
import operator

sorted(my_list, key=operator.itemgetter("name"))
```

Also, `itemgetter` can take a few arguments, and returns a tuple of those items, so you can sort on a number of keys like this:

```
sorted(my_list, key=operator.itemgetter("name", "age", "other_thing"))
```

The `sorted` function returns a new sorted list.  If you want to sort the list in place, use:

```
my_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter("name"))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to sort the list.

Comment: @Will: I've updated the answer: sorted returns a new list, but you can also sort in place.