# iphone facebook - getting friends list alphabetical order using Graph API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Folks,

i am developing a iphone app which list the user's fb friends list. Here am using FBGraph API for listing.. problem here is it returning friends list in random order not in a particular sequence . Here i wants this to display in alphabetical order.

is It possible to get the friends list from fb in alphabetical order using graph API (or) to how to make it as alphabetic...

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499896/sorting-facebook-album-photos-using-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

From FB its not yet provided anything in graph API.

[You can go through this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5048841/687692) to get some idea.

Comment: ya am already did the same thing only .i just need to verify is there anything like so.. finally array sorting is did the magic.. any way thanks for your suggestion.