# Sorting facebook album photos using graph Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get last 7 updated images from album folder. I used reverse_chronological as well as chronological but its not working. Based on time update i have to sort the images.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{albumid}/photos?&field=id,created_time.order(reverse_chronological),description&limit=7&access_token={zxczczxczx}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation around [ordering](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#ordering), this format should work:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{album-id}/?fields=photos.order(reverse_chronological)
```

Can you try that?

Comment: Hey, it does not work for me, the order is not affected. I'm using v3.1. and here is my fields specification: `/<album-id>?fields=cover_photo{source}&count&link&photos.order(reverse_chronological).limit(100){source,created_time}`. Any idea?